# Routing requests by Spring Cloud Gateway on K8s to the AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, spring-cloud, amazon-eks

I am stuck on the implementation of one thing.

I have an AWS EKS cluster with Pods hosted on the EC2 instances.
As a Gateway I use Spring Cloud Kubernetes and do routing of requests to my microservices. All microservices a hosted on the EC2 nodegroup.

Now we want to migrate some additional work from the Docker container on the k8s pods to AWS Lambda.

I want to route my requests by Spring Cloud Gateway to my lambda as an example:

```
        - id: testing
          uri: https://xxxxxxxxxxx.lambda-url.eu-central-1.on.aws
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/tests
```

I created an AWS Lambda on the same VPC as my AWS EKS cluster.
To protect my Lambda from not authorized requests I put the Auth type as AWS_IAM.

I added policy `AWSLambdaRole` to the AIM Profile role that is attached to my AWS EKS cluster EC2 instances.
But when I send a request to my API with path `/api/v1/tests` I receive a message `{"Message": "Forbidden"}`.

What policy I should modify or attach to my current EC2 node groups that they have access to the Invoke Function of my AWS Lambda?